# How can I order posts by a sub field in a repeater field of ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have on a wordpress website 2 CPT:

- Lessons
- Routes

The lessons are related to routes with a Relation field from ACF with meta key "relazione_percorso".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnzOw.png)

The problem is that a lesson can be related to 1 ore more routes, but I need a custom position order for each routes.

For example Lesson 1 can be related to Route 1 in position 4 AND on the Route 3 in position 9.

To give a custom order of the lesson to the route, I added a Repeater field with meta key "posizione_nel_percorso".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6E2M.png)

Then I added 2 sub-fields:

- A Posts Field from ACF with meta key "lista_percorsi" so I can choose the routes from the list
- A numeric field with meta key "posizione_della_lezione_nel_percorso" where I add a number, like in the screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKkxC.png)

Now the problem is that I cannot order the lessons in a route by "posizione_della_lezione_nel_percorso" which is the numeric field.

Save

I did something like this:

- Show lessons WHERE meta key "relazione_percorso" LIKE current_ID (and it works)
- Show lessons WHERE meta key "posizione_nel_percorso" and left it blank (and it works)
- Show lessons WHERE meta key "lista_percorsi" EXISTS and it shows me 0. No posts anymore

Even if I do just ORDER BY "posizione_della_lezione_nel_percorso" ASC it doesn't show me any posts.

So basically I cannot get data from the subfields of the repeater field.

What am I missing?

PS: Using Query Builder from Jetengine

Meta query posts:

- [List item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoFOI.png)
- [List item 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIQuy.png)
- [Order by](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGJqC.png)

Comment: And what is your query ?

Comment: I am using Jetengine Querybuilder. I just edited the content

Comment: Have you checked how your `lista_percorsi` sub-field is actually stored in the database? I doubt that the key name is _just_ that - see https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/repeater-data-in-database/#post-95715

Comment: Oh...Seems that now If I do "posizione_nel_percorso_0_lista_percorsi", as in the link you gave me it works.

They say that the field must be composed by repeater + index + sub field